# AutoLisp - Find AppData

Tags: lisp, appdata, autolisp

I'm having trouble in finding AppData with the parent folder. Originally, my plan was to pull the username, use it to get to `C:\Users\[User]\AppData\Roaming\DraftSight`, and create a [text file](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/text-files/info) with the few variables needed for the add-in. However, I've run into an issue where neither the results of `(getenv "LoginName")` and `(getenv "UserName")` match the name of the parent directory of AppData.

On my quest to find an alternative way to find AppData, I found information in a website, [AfraLisp](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/visual-lisp-autolisp-and-general/how-to-get-the-full-username-again/td-p/1664977), where it shows how to use `setcfg` and `getcfg` in AutoLisp, but the results I receive from these commands is `nil`. These commands save this information in a file called AppData.ini, but I'm not sure where it is located.

**Questions**

1. How do does my add-in need to be able to access the AppData directory?
2. Where is the AppData.ini file located? Is this file still in use?

**Website References:**

- AutoDesk Form: [`(getvar "LoginName")` and `(getvar "UserName")`](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/visual-lisp-autolisp-and-general/how-to-get-the-full-username-again/td-p/1664977)
- AfraLisp: [`setcfg` and `getcfg`](https://www.afralisp.net/autolisp/tutorials/application-data.php)
- SolidWorks Reference: [`getenv`](https://help.solidworks.com/2022/english/api/draftsightlispreference/html/lisp_function_getenv.htm)
- SolidWorks Reference: [`getcfg`](https://help.solidworks.com/2022/english/api/draftsightlispreference/html/lisp_function_getcfg.htm?id=e590e3c69d3e4ecc9f53604a78efd7df#Pg0)
- SolidWorks Reference: [`setcfg`](https://help.solidworks.com/2022/english/api/draftsightlispreference/html/lisp_function_setcfg.htm?id=ba218018c4d24915bcd61424ba199519#Pg0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am still clueless with the AppData.ini file, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359338/windows-equivalent-of-system-configuration-directory) contained the answer I was looking to find in regards to the first question. Simply use `(getenv [Input])` with the names below to receive their respective file paths.

1. `(getenv "APPDATA")` ----------> `"C:\Users\AppData\Roaming"`
2. `(getenv "LOCALAPPDATA")` -----> `"C:\Users\AppData\Local"`
3. `(getenv "ALLUSERSPROFILE")` --> `"C:\ProgramData"`